# How can I rearrange a DataFrame with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame:

```
                 Amount                           dwy                                         bmd
Portfolio   EUR GBP JPY USD                 EUR GBP JPY USD                          EUR    GBP JPY USD
date
2016-05-13  100 200 300 400                -0.5 0.5 0   0.8                          3.8    3   0   3
```

and I would like to transfer it to this:

```
date        ccy             amt       dwy   bmd
2016-05-13  EUR             100      -0.5   3.8
2016-05-13  GBP             200       0.5   3
2016-05-13  JPY             300       0     0
2016-05-13  USD             400       0.8   3
```

I have tried `df.stack()` and `df.unstack` and also `df.T` in a variety of ways.  Other than pull this apart piece by piece and reassemble is is there a more optimal way?

Comment: The dataframe seems to be gereated from some other frame by pivoting, maybe directly modifying that step would be easier. Can you show original data? Is this a multilevel dataframe?

Comment: it is multilevel.  I will use what you posted below.  What I should do is incorporate a DataFrame earlier in workflow but this adds other complications due to NANs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pd.DataFrame(df.stack("Currency").to_records())` Should do the trick.

Here's an explanation of the steps:

**1. Reproducing your dataframe:**

```
arrays = [['Amount', 'Amount', 'Amount', 'Amount', 'dwy', 'dwy', 'dwy', 'dwy', 'bmd', 'bmd', 'bmd', 'bmd'],
          ['EUR', 'GBP', 'JPY', 'USD', 'EUR', 'GBP', 'JPY', 'USD', 'EUR', 'GBP', 'JPY', 'USD']]

tuples = list(zip(*arrays))

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['Portfolio', 'Currency'])

data = [100, 200, 300, 400, -0.5, 0.5, 0, 0.8, 3.8, 3, 0, 3]

df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
df.columns = index
df.index = ['2016-05-13']
```

*Here's the "Input" DataFrame:*

```
Portfolio  Amount                 dwy                bmd            
Currency      EUR  GBP  JPY  USD  EUR  GBP JPY  USD  EUR GBP JPY USD
2016-05-13    100  200  300  400 -0.5  0.5   0  0.8  3.8   3   0   3
```

**2. Calling `df.stack("Currency")` will stack on the *Currency* column:**

```
Portfolio            Amount  bmd  dwy
           Currency                  
2016-05-13 EUR          100  3.8 -0.5
           GBP          200  3.0  0.5
           JPY          300  0.0  0.0
           USD          400  3.0  0.8
```

**3. *Close* but not quite. We just need to flatten the index of the Dataframe. To do this, we can call `to_records()`:**

```
3. df.stack("Currency").to_records()

# Result:
# => rec.array([('2016-05-13', 'EUR', 100.0, 3.8, -0.5),
 ('2016-05-13', 'GBP', 200.0, 3.0, 0.5),
 ('2016-05-13', 'JPY', 300.0, 0.0, 0.0),
 ('2016-05-13', 'USD', 400.0, 3.0, 0.8)], 
          dtype=[('level_0', 'S10'), ('Currency', 'S3'), ('Amount', '<f8'), ('bmd', '<f8'), ('dwy', '<f8')])
```

**4. Then we can recreate the dataframe with a new index:**

```
pd.DataFrame(df.stack("Currency").to_records())

      level_0 Currency  Amount  bmd  dwy
0  2016-05-13      EUR     100  3.8 -0.5
1  2016-05-13      GBP     200  3.0  0.5
2  2016-05-13      JPY     300  0.0  0.0
3  2016-05-13      USD     400  3.0  0.8
```

From here, you can can simply rename and reorder your columns if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I got that too and accidently pasted the old code. You can fix it by transposing the initial dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame(data).T`

Comment: Why just not `df.stack("Currency").reset_index()` or with setting index `df.stack("Currency").reset_index().set_index('level_0')`?

Comment: @Anthony this is great except your DataFrame is slightly different, I got it working in anycase and have learned a new feature of pandas.

Comment: @AntonProtopopov Because I felt that the crux of the problem was data shaping and manipulation. Naming columns was a relatively trivial step and not closely related to the problem at hand.

Comment: @AnthonyE It's not naming, instead of converting dataframe to records and constracting new one you could do `reset_index` for the original stacked dataframe.

Comment: @AnthonyE Is it better to work with multiple single dataframes (a dataframe for each measure) or a single multi level dataframes with multiple measures?

Comment: @toasteez I'm assuming by measure you mean each hierarchical column? Generally, it's best to use a single multi-level dataframe as it will be be easier and perhaps also simpler to query.

Comment: @AnthonyE an example of measure would be for example price, return, weight with other fields being index_date, portfolio (currency). If I were to `dfs_pivot = dfs.pivot(index='index_date', columns='Portfolio (Currency)')`  the dataframe would have the measures above the `Portfolio (Currency)` how do you manipulate a frame to have them under the `Portfolio (Currency)` such that 1 Portfolio (Currency) has many measures?

Answer (score 0):

You have not given code, so I am also answering without code also:

- You could generate 4 dataframes for EUR, GDP, JPY and USD. For the example of EUR, you would simply only select the columns which contain EUR in their column name and add one additional column ccy which contains the value 'EUR'
- You would then simply append those 4 dataframes together and sort them according to date.